# R does not build my project after several weeks with no changes

Tags: r, rstudio

A bit frustrated right now. I have an R project that I built several weeks ago that I have not touched in those weeks. Come back to R Studio to do some debugging, and it will not rebuild the package. When I run the Check command from within the RStudio UI, the error I get is:

```
Error: Check failed: 'P:\MosaicPA\R Packages/Mosaic.VoronoiV2.Rcheck' doesn't exist
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

When I try the Install and Restart option, I get this error:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source Mosaic.VoronoiV2

Warning: invalid package 'Mosaic.VoronoiV2'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified

Exited with status 1.
```

I have not seen these messages before, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, since nothing has changed.

I am not new to programming, but I am new-ish to the R environment. Cannot figure out what has changed, and I dont know what the .Rcheck file is, and I dont know why R doesnt create it. None of my other projects have a .Rcheck file or directory, and I dont know if this is supposed to be a file or directory. I have tried creating the project from scratch. Same issue.

Using R 3.4.1 and the latest R Studio version.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Windows permissions strikes again...personally, I find Windows to be a HUGE POS because of stuff like this. Problem resolved after I reinstalled R under my domain account...I was suspicious of this, but couldn't find a way to confirm. Just reinstalled R and it worked. What I really wish is that when it IS a permissions problem, that Windows would report it as such, so the software can tell the end user this, vs sending us down some rabbit hole, chasing some non-existent problem, which happens too much as it is. Thanks, Redmond! But...I understand...after all, MS is too busy working on the next emoji standard...which is a priority, so who has time to make the OS better. End of rant.